# Azure - cannot connect to database

Tags: azure

Known error:

> Database 'X' on server 'Y' is not currently available.  Please retry
>   the connection later.  If the problem persists, contact customer
>   support, and provide them the session tracing ID of
>   '{DE0B6749-0D1B-4D6F-8102-86D1A7A35AD2}'.

The problem is: I need to pay for customer support (I do not see free plan, despite I have paid for web app!)

Connection is fine from azure web site. THe problem occurs while connecting from external computer (f. e. from my local).

What could be the problem? Yestarday everything worked fine.

Comment: global outage happening. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/status/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is due to a transient service outage; unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Azure goes down. Check Azure status on :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/status/

For this particular case, the problem was:

"Starting at 11:48 UTC 15 Sep, 2016 a subset of customers using DNS in multiple regions may experience difficulties connecting to their resources hosted in this region. This issue is also having knock-on impact on impact on multiple Azure services, including SQL Database, Virtual Machines, Visual Studio Team Services, and App Service \ Web Apps. Engineers are aware of this issue and are actively investigating. The next update will be provided in 60 minutes, or as events warrant."

Comment: Please don't post this as an answer - it's a transient issue that should be posted as a comment, and the question should be closed (and the answer itself should be deleted).

Comment: Yes, was a transient service outage, but the transient service outage was the cause of problem... Why is not valid?. User could waste a lot of time until he notice about the problem... The situation could present again in the future...

Comment: It's not valid because 1) it's not a programming question and doesn't fit on StackOverflow and 2) the question (and answer) is only valid for the events from this morning. The service incident is already over. And there's no more relevance to this.  This is the same guidance that should be followed for *any* service outage (regardless whether cloud, hosted, code-repositories, etc.).